# Android VideoFrame is a null pointer exception

Tags: android, video, camera, mediarecorder

I am trying to create my own custom camera in android which would start recording when the user touches 
the surface view of the camera preview and stops recording when the user takes his finger off the surface view . The trouble is that by holding his finger less than 2 seconds i get a "video frame is a null pointer " . I have to deal with this problem because i need to be able to film very short sequences of videos and then concatenate them . I would like to find a workaround this problem !